# C# setting bool property from radio button

Tags: c#, properties, boolean, stack-overflow

I have a problem with my radio buttons. What I'm doing is I create a customer object and at the same time I want to set one bool property of each radio button in the customer base class. The error message I get is "StackOverflowException Was Unhandeled". The error is pointing at this "IsClient = value;" in the CustomerType class.

Here is where I create the Customer object (inside CustomerForm.cs)

```
m_customer = new Customer(radioClient.Checked, radioProspect.Checked, radioCompany.Checked, radioPrivate.Checked);


public class Customer : CustomerType
{
private Contact m_contact;
private string m_id;

public Customer()
{
    m_id = string.Empty;
}

public Customer(bool client, bool prospect, bool company, bool priv)
{
    base.IsClient = client;
    base.IsProspect = prospect;
    base.IsCompany = company;
    base.IsPrivate = priv;
    m_id = string.Empty;
}

public Customer(Contact contactData)
{ m_contact = contactData; }

public Customer(string id, Contact contact)
{
    m_id = id;
    m_contact = contact;
}

public Contact ContactData
{
    get { return m_contact; }
    set {
        if (value != null)
            m_contact = value;  
    }
}

public string Id
{
    get { return m_id; }
    set { m_id = value; }
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return m_contact.ToString();
}
}


public class CustomerType 
{

public bool IsClient
{
    get { return IsClient; }
    set { IsClient = value; }
}

public bool IsCompany
{
    get { return IsCompany; }
    set { IsCompany = value; }
}

public bool IsPrivate
{
    get { return IsPrivate; }
    set { IsPrivate = value; }
}

public bool IsProspect
{
    get { return IsProspect; }
    set { IsProspect = value; }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the properties in your `CustomerType` are recursive - they blow the stack.

Take a look at this:

```
public bool IsClient
{
    get { return IsClient; }
    set { IsClient = value; }
}
```

When you try to get the value of the `IsClient` property, you then try to get the value of the `IsClient` property. Which then tries to get the value of the `IsClient` property ...

Either implement these as automatically implemented properties:

```
public bool IsClient
{
    get; set;
}
```

Or have a proper backing field:

```
private bool isClient;
public bool IsClient
{
    get { return isClient; }
    set { isClient = value; }
}
```

Comment: @jameslewis - That's one option.

Comment: THANKS!! I went with the automatic implemented property and it works fine!

Comment: @user1051477 - Just remember to do this with _all_ of your properties, not just `IsClient`.

Answer (score 1):

A property is a function.  What you wrote is the equivalent of writing:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    DoSomething();  // infinite recursion
}
```

Error code:

```
public bool IsClient
{
    get { return IsClient; }
    set { IsClient = value; }
}
```

Proper code:

```
public bool IsClient
{
    get { return _isClient; }
    set { _isClient = value; }
}
private bool _isClient;
```

Or in C# 3.0 or later, you can use auto implemented properties for simple ones:

```
public bool IsClient { get; set; }
```